# Too many requests in batch message. Maximum batch size is 50 when batch request facebook api?

Tags: facebook

When I batch request insights data using `facebook marketing api`

```py
request_list = []

for campaign_id in campaign_id_list:
    params = {
        "time_range": json.dumps({"since": "2018-02-12", "until": "2019-02-20"}),
        "level": "campaign",
        "fields": "name,clicks,spend,campaign_id",
    }

    d = {
        "method": "GET",
        "relative_url": "{}/{}/insights?".format(config["fb"]["api_version"], 
    campaign_id) + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    }
    request_list.append(d)

data = {
"access_token": "dasdasdwqewqe",
"batch": json.dumps(request_list)}


ret = requests.Session().post(url,data=data)
```

error appeared:

```
msg="{'fbtrace_id': 'Fla01kV7oKM', 'type': 'GraphBatchException', 'message': 'Too many requests in batch message. Maximum batch size is 50'}
```

Doesn't it support batch requests in insights type api ? If it is how can I make it right? thanks

Comment: Does request_list only contain this one single request as shown above, or is that actually filled inside of a loop or something?

Comment: @thanks for your replying,  it is in a loop. I 've updated it above

Comment: And how many sub-request are you adding there? More than the 50 the message mentioned, presumably?

Comment: @04FS  just 54 requests  added